# Can a Turing Machine compute the binary representation of $n!$ in $O(n!)$ time?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

We can compute the binary representation of $n$ and similarly by decrementing the value of $n$ by $1$ each time we can get all values from $2$ to $n$. We can now use a Turing Machine that multiplies binary numbers to get the value of $n$. But will this computation be bounded by $O(n)$? That is, can $n!$ be a time constructible function?

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55761/prove-n-is-fully-time-constructible

Comment: It might be useful to mention what definition of time constructible you are referring to ([there is at least a couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constructible)) as well as whether the input $n$ is given either in unary or binary.

Comment: $n$ is given in binary. Here time constructible would refer to producing the binary representation in $O(f(n))$ time